# linux sed script to make first letter of each word uppercase

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to make a sed script that will make the first letter of each

```
molly w. bolt     334-78-5443
walter q. bugg    984-49-0032
noah p. way       887-12-0921
```

So I want it to look like this:

```
Molly W. Bolt     334-78-5443
Walter Q. Bugg    984-49-0032
Noah P. Way       887-12-0921
```

So far I have the following script, but it will only capitalize the first two words it comes across ie. making it Molly W. bolt. I can't figure out how to modify the script to get the last name uppercase. What do I need to add?

```
h
s/\(.\).*/\1/
y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
G
s/\(.\)\n\(.\)\(.*\)/\1\3/
/ [a-z]/{
    h
    s/\([A-Z][a-z]* \)\([a-z]\).*/\2/
    y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
    G
    s/\(.\)\n\([A-Z][a-z]* \)\(.\)\(.*\)/\2\1\4/
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this gnu sed one liner may help you:

```
sed 's/\b./\u&/g' file
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
molly w. bolt 334-78-5443
walter q. bugg 984-49-0032
noah p. way 887-12-0921

kent$  sed 's/\b./\u&/g' f
Molly W. Bolt 334-78-5443
Walter Q. Bugg 984-49-0032
Noah P. Way 887-12-0921
```

Comment: How would I make this into a script?

Comment: @Joe just put it in your script? don't know your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use the word boundary `\b` and `\U` to uppercase:

```
sed 's/\b./\U&/g'
```